# Exchange online and zimbra on premise mail server sharing same domain

Tags: office365, exchange, zimbra

Am planning to Migrate my Zimbra mail server to Exchange Online but in the meantime, I need to configure some users (30 users) on Exchange Online and the rest on the Zimbra mail server version 8.8.15 (250 users), while maintaining the same domain eg xyz.com on both users on exchange online and Zimbra on-premise

is this possible?
any guide or documentation on such?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

If your email domain's MX record is pointing to Exchange Online, you need to configure xyz.com as an internal relay domain, then create a send connector in Exchange Online to route emails sent to users on Zimbra to the Zimbra server.

Exchange Online documentation:

[Manage accepted domains in Exchange Online (refer to the Internal relay part)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/manage-accepted-domains/manage-accepted-domains)

[Set up connectors to route mail between Microsoft 365 or Office 365 and your own email servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail)